# Image control of Xamarin Forms TapGestureRecognizer is not working on some parts of the image(Xamarin Forms IOS))

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**XAML**

```
 Image x:Name="Image" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" IsVisible="False"
```

[image]

**.CS**

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = (ICommand) newvalue,
                CommandParameter = CommandParameter
            };
            Image.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
            Image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

I tried to add an image to the stacklayout in Xamarin forms and added TapGestureRecognizer for the image. I added that tap works for some areas but not for others (right corners, top corners, etc.). The taps in the middle of the image work pretty well. How can I add TapGestureRecognizer work for the whole area, even corners of the image?
**This happens on iOS devices.** **On Android it works well**

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying adding Tap gesture to the stacklayout so that the image inside the stacklayout is clickable anywhere in iOS.